# How can i write a MATLAB function named dedbi that takes input xtx as string and returns another string xtxx as output.

Tags: matlab

dedbi  reverse the words that is, ‘a’ will be replaced by ‘z’, ‘b’ will be replaced by ‘y’,  ‘c’ will be replaced by ‘x’ and so on.  dedbi  will do the same for capital letter that is, it will replace the string ‘A’ with ‘Z’, ‘B’ with ‘Y’, ‘C’ with ‘X’, and so on. If I give function this string  ‘ab AB’ function should return ‘zy ZY’, input other than English words it will return input as output that is input as  ‘///\?’ would return  output as ‘///\?’.

So far i write this code. I must admit this problem is from an assignment that I need to pass.
Thank You guys for your kind look.

```
function xtxx = dedbi(xtx)
txtt = char(xtx);
indexa = strfind(txtt,'a');
txtt(indexa) = 'z';
indA = strfind(txtt,'A');
txtt(indA) = 'Z';
indb = strfind(txtt,'b');
txtt(indb) = 'y';
indB = strfind(txtt,'B');
txtt(indB) = 'Y';
indc = strfind(txtt,'c');
txtt(indc) = 'x';
indC = strfind(txtt,'C');
txtt(indC) = 'X';
indd = strfind(txtt,'d');
txtt(indd) = 'w';
indD = strfind(txtt,'D');
txtt(indD) = 'W';
inde = strfind(txtt,'e');
txtt(inde) = 'v';
indE = strfind(txtt,'E');
txtt(indE) = 'V';
indf = strfind(txtt,'f');
txtt(indf) = 'u';
indF = strfind(txtt,'F');
txtt(indF) = 'U';
indg = strfind(txtt,'g');
txtt(indg) = 't';
indG = strfind(txtt,'G');
txtt(indG) = 'T';
indh = strfind(txtt,'h');
txtt(indh) = 's';
indH = strfind(txtt,'H');
txtt(indH) = 'S';
indi = strfind(txtt,'i');
txtt(indi) = 'r';
indI = strfind(txtt,'I');
txtt(indI) = 'R';
indj = strfind(txtt,'j');
txtt(indj) = 'q';
indJ = strfind(txtt,'J');
txtt(indJ) = 'Q';
indk = strfind(txtt,'k');
txtt(indk) = 'p';
indK = strfind(txtt,'K');
txtt(indK) = 'P';
indl = strfind(txtt,'l');
txtt(indl) = 'o';
indL = strfind(txtt,'L');
txtt(indL) = 'O';
indm = strfind(txtt,'m');
txtt(indm) = 'n';
indM = strfind(txtt,'M');
txtt(indM) = 'N';
indn = strfind(txtt,'n');
txtt(indn) = 'm';
indN = strfind(txtt,'N');
txtt(indN) = 'M';
indo = strfind(txtt,'o');
txtt(indo) = 'l';
indO = strfind(txtt,'O');
txtt(indO) = 'L';
indp = strfind(txtt,'p');
txtt(indp) = 'k';
indP = strfind(txtt,'P');
txtt(indP) = 'K';
indq = strfind(txtt,'q');
txtt(indq) = 'j';
indQ = strfind(txtt,'Q');
txtt(indQ) = 'J';
indr = strfind(txtt,'r');
txtt(indr) = 'i';
indR = strfind(txtt,'R');
txtt(indR) = 'I';
inds = strfind(txtt,'s');
txtt(inds) = 'h';
indS = strfind(txtt,'S');
txtt(indS) = 'H';
indt = strfind(txtt,'t');
txtt(indt) = 'g';
indT = strfind(txtt,'T');
txtt(indT) = 'G';
indu = strfind(txtt,'u');
txtt(indu) = 'f';
indU = strfind(txtt,'U');
txtt(indU) = 'F';
indv = strfind(txtt,'v');
indv(txtt) = 'e';
indV = strfind(txtt,'V');
txtt(indV) = 'E';
indw = strfind(txtt,'w');
txtt(indw) = 'd';
indW = strfind(txtt,'W');
txtt(indW) = 'D';
indx = strfind(txtt,'x');
txtt(indx) = 'c';
indX = strfind(txtt,'X');
txtt(indX) = 'C';
indy = strfind(txtt,'y');
txtt(indy) = 'b';
indY = strfind(txtt,'Y');
txtt(indY) = 'B';
indz = strfind(txtt,'z');
txtt(indz) = 'a';
indZ = strfind(txtt,'Z');
txtt(indZ) = 'A';

str = xtxx;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach -

```
%// in_str: Input string

%// Logical masks for upper and lower case letters
upper_mask = in_str>=65 & in_str<=90  %// OR isstrprop(in_str,'upper')
lower_mask = in_str>=97 & in_str<=122 %// OR isstrprop(in_str,'lower')

%// Initialize output string
out_str = in_str

%// Replace upper letters with "flipped" upper letters; repeat for small letters
out_str(upper_mask) = char(in_str(upper_mask) + 2*(78-in_str(upper_mask))-1)
out_str(lower_mask) = char(in_str(lower_mask) + 2*(110-in_str(lower_mask))-1)
```

Those numbers: `78` and `110` act as the "middle numbers" for the capital and small letters ranges respectively and are used for finding differences for each letter in those two categories.

Sample run -

```
>> in_str,out_str
in_str =
adzC+*6AY&‘///\?abAB
out_str =
zwaX+*6ZB&‘///\?zyZY
```

Comment: Thank You. i think i have to struggle to understand your code for few hours as i am newbie in MATLAB as well as programming.

Comment: @DumbCoder A lot of it involves dealing with ascii equivalents, look here for the table list of it : http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: thank you bro, your hints helped to solve this problem but i think i need to spend more time with your code to understand fully. This is the second time you helped me on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz';
ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
ralphabet = fliplr(alphabet);
RALPHABET = fliplr(ALPHABET);

txt = 'abc d ?!.< n AC';

[~, index] = ismember(txt,alphabet);
target  = index ~= 0;
src     = index(target);

[~, INDEX] = ismember(txt,ALPHABET);
TARGET  = INDEX ~= 0;
SRC     = INDEX(TARGET);

txtInvert = txt;
txtInvert(target) = ralphabet(src);
txtInvert(TARGET) = RALPHABET(SRC);
```

Output:

zyx w ?!.< n ZX

Comment: Thank you. Could pleas provide some links to understand using ~ in [ ]. I am really confused about it.

Comment: If matlab when a function returns more than one parameter you can use `[par1, par2, ... parN] = myFunction()` By default, if you say `par = myFunction()` than it only takes the first return. When you only want a returned parameter that is _not_ the first, you can say `[~, par]`, in which case the first returner parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted the solution, than I realised that I probably shouldn't solve your assignment. Anyways, here are a couple of tips for you:

1. You can use the function `fliplr()` to invert the elements in a (row) vector. (hint: reverse the alphabet)
2. If you do: `[~, index] = ismember('abcd','ac')`, than `index` will be: `index=[1 3]` (hint: the index of 'a' and `c` in the alphabet are the same as for `z` and 'y' in the reverse alphabet)

Comment: Thank you bro for your hint. As a newbie in MATLAB as well as programming i think i need to understand and think more clearly about this problem. Definitely your hint will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
function out = func_name(in)
    in = array of ascii values from original in values (can be done with one command)
    out = vector if zeros the size of in (one command)
    loop through all numbers of in
        ch = current char ascii value (just because it is easier to write ch than in(index) in my opinion)
        if ch is btw 65 and 96
            subtract 65 so ch is 1-26
            find 26-ch (invert)
            add 65 so ch is 65-96
        if ch is btw  97 and 122
            do the same as above with adjusted numbers
        end if
        out(index_of_for_loop) = ch
    end loop
end function
```

Note: In general, it is best to avoid code that has many copy-paste section because it can be difficult to edit quickly.

Comment: Thank you bro for your code. As i am learning ASCII for the first time, i think your code needs a little correction in first IF statement. I think it would be between 65 and 90, right? Another question is as my function takes string so why do not i use func_name('in')? or should i type the second line of code like in = double('in')?

Comment: There's a lot of edits you'll have to make as this is pseudo code.  It just gives a general idea of how to tackle this.

Comment: 'out = vector if zeros the size of in (one command)' do not get this line enough. Please explain a bit.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to see this.  In MATLAB you generally want to make arrays the right size before you use them. This line is supposed to make an array for use as output.  The array will be an n-by-1 array of zeros.  There is a built in command that will do this, and the syntax (I think) is zeros(n,m) for an n-by-m array or zeros(n) for an n-by-n array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
function xtx = dedbi(xtx)
    xtx(xtx >= 'a' & xtx <= 'z') = 219 - xtx(xtx >= 'a' & xtx <= 'z');
    xtx(xtx >= 'A' & xtx <= 'Z') = 155 - xtx(xtx >= 'A' & xtx <= 'Z');
end
```